# how to move excel file data to sql using bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, excel, bulkinsert

i want to move all my data from excel files to tables in sql, dynamically.
I have used below procedure. but no luck. Plz help.

```
alter PROCEDURE SP_InsertTotables @tablename nvarchar(max),@filelocation nvarchar(max)
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    AS
BEGIN

    declare @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

Set @sql= 'BULK INSERT '+@tablename +' FROM '''+@filelocation+''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',FIRSTROW = 2)'




print @sql;
```

go

Comment: What error message are you getting? You need to add an `END`

Comment: Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: @statement isn't referenced anywhere...

Comment: This is dynamically taking the parametes so its considering @statement

Comment: i want to know whether BULK INSERT works for moving excel data to sql?

Comment: Yes, best would be to use a CSV and you'll need to include the filename with the file location. But there are issues with the SP, check this out: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/